# Windows 7: determine which process created a named pipe?

Tags: windows, process, pipe, named

I am wondering what is the way(s) to determine which process created a named pipe in Windows 7. I am interested in discovering strange processes that created named pipes.
Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: [You'll need ETW for that](https://github.com/kobykahane/NpEtw)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Many thanks for the suggestion. Is this the only way (I am asking as I might not have the authority to install the suggested ETW)?

Comment: I can't think of any other feasible method off the top of my head, no.